# Why Postman and Fiddler never generate preflight request

Tags: api, http, fiddler, postman

When ever I request to API through Postman or Fiddler never generate Preflight request. Both tool always generate Post or Get request. But when we are generating the request from file or other source then it first generate Preflight request and send HTTP OPTIONS.

Regards,

Comment: i would love to be able to generate a preflight request from postman for testing, but for some reason when i send HTTP OPTIONS from postman it is not flagged as preflight by my java server, even when i use all the headers: 'Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Origin'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for that is because the CORS only applies to sandboxed environments, like the browser. When making a direct HTTP request with Fiddler you don't need any CORS. The pre-flight request is sent by the browser before sending the actual request to ensure that CORS is enabled.

Comment: But then what if the browser breaks with an error like `Access to XMLHttpRequest at X from origin 'Y' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`